# PHP - Javascript - Laravel : JavaScript::put - Method not found

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to access data of my PHP from Javascript to format my page. I'm using **Laravel** framework.

I'm storing some information in a database, I'm getting them from PHP, and I use these information to format my page differently according to the user logged. Information in the DB are not used only for this purpose.

To format my page I'm using some JavaScript, so I need to access these data in my JavaScript.

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

But I still can't access my data. It's telling me that the method `put` was not found in JavaScript.

Here is my bit of code:

file.blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@include('footer')

<div class="container">
    Code for my page here. 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(age);
</script>

@endsection
```

javascript.php:

```
<?php

return [
'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'footer',
'js_namespace' => 'window'
];
```

controller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use JavaScript;

class BusLine extends Model
{

public function index()
{

    JavaScript::put([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'age' => 29
    ]);

    return View::make('hello');
}

protected $table='bus_line';

protected $fillable = [
    'ID', 'card_uid', 'bus_direction'
];
}
```

My footer.blade.php is empty, I added `Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptServiceProvider::class` and `'JavaScript' => Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptFacade::class` to app.php

I tried a few things like doing the PHP in another file and nothing changed. Always the same message. Maybe I've missed an installation step.

I'm totally new to Laravel / PHP so maybe my code is not structured correctly.

Comment: Have you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: @aynber I just did it and no result, even after restarting the project.

Comment: @Joe : Where should I put that? And how? If I put that in the HTML part, it will print that on the page, in the JavaScript that's not recognized,  (I'm a total newbie, the guy before me started using that, and he's the only one in the company).

Comment: Have you tried to include Laracast/Utilites library ? <br > composer require laracasts/utilities

Comment: In the project that I am working on there is a slash before JavaScript, maybe you need to do that too? (I am new to Laravel too)  \JavaScript::put([..